# Alternative ways to instantiate a class in Python

Tags: python

I am currently writing my python classes and instantiate them like this

```
class calculations_class():
    def calculate(self):
        return True

Calculations = calculations_class()
```

I was wondering if I was doing this correctly, or if there were any other ways to instantiate them. Thanks!

Comment: Your variable names and class names are totally backwards.  Class Names Begin With Capital Letters.  variable names begin with lower-case letters.  Class Names NEVER End in `_class`, since that's obvious and doesn't bear repeating.

Comment: You mean "instantiate" as in "create an instance", not "initiate" which means "to begin". You're probably conflating instantiation and initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the naming convention issue which other answers have correctly pointed out, you're basically fine: calling a class is indeed by far the most common way of instantiating that class.  If you need any per-instance *initialization* (most typically setting some instance-attributes to initial values), be sure to define an `__init__` method that performs it:

```
class Calculations(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.running_total = 0  # or w/ever
  def calculate(self):
    ...

calc = Calculations()
```

The other, rare ways of instantiating a class typically occur when you want to *bypass* the initialization part for some reason (e.g., in the course of de-serializing an instance from some file, database, or communication from other processes -- the `pickle` module is a good example of needing such advanced approaches).  I don't think you should worry about them at all at this stage of your Python learning experience.

Answer (score 4):

Well, class names tend to be capitalized (and camelcase) and instance names tend to be lowercase, but further that's the way to go.

```
class CalculationsClass():
    def calculate(self):
        return True

my_calc_instance = CalculationsClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way. Only thing you should do differently: class names should start with an uppercase letter, and variables with a lowercase one.

Answer (score -2):

I tend to use the following format:

```
class CCalculations():        #Classes always begin with "C"
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 0
        self.fooBar = 0       #Variables use camelCase

    def DoCalculations(self): #Methods use uppercase
        return true

    def getFoo(self): 
        return self.foo       #getters and setters use camelCase
```

The reasons for this are varied:

1. Putting "C" in front of the class name easily separates what is a class and what is a method/function. This is especially useful if you're using a good IDE (I use WingIDE). So all of your classes are located in one spot because all of them start with C. Also, it makes code more readable since you know for sure you are instancing a class and not calling a function.
2. Using capital letters for regular methods and camelCase for getters and setters means that more important regular methods are not cluttering up the namespace with gets/sets. So within the class, since things go in ASCII-betical order, your real methods come first and your getters and setters last.
3. Class names should be nouns. Methods should be verbs that describe actions the noun can do. Attributes should be nouns that describe how the noun looks.

Comment: Why provide a getFoo() method if the foo attribute is public?

Comment: This is breaking quite a few Python conventions. i) As others mention, use CamelCase for class names (don't use `C`-prefix). ii) Variables use snake_case. iii) Getters and setters don't belong in Python. iv) Methods use snake_case. v) `DoCalculations` could be a static method (but perhaps the example was kept to a minimal and use of `self` ommited).